# Angular RxJs TypeError "undefined"

Tags: node.js, angular, rxjs, subject

Sorry if this question doesn't make sense, I'm very new to the MEAN stack. I have been trying to get an array from an express middleware to display on an angular frontend. The problem I have been having is even though everything compiles and appears to work I get an error in the console saying "ERROR TypeError: 'this.brackets is undefined'".

This is the code that appears to be the problem

'''

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Bracket } from './bracket.model';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
private brackets: Bracket[] = [];
private bracketsUpdated = new Subject<Bracket[]>();

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

getBracket() {
    this.http.get<{message: string, brackets: Bracket[]}>('http://localhost:3000/api/brackets')
    .subscribe((bracketData) => {
        this.brackets = bracketData.brackets;
        this.bracketsUpdated.next([...this.brackets]); // this is the problem line
    });
    console.log(this.brackets);
}
```

'''

and this is where the array is coming from

'''

```
app.use("/api/brackets", (req, res, next)=>{
    const bracket= [
        {
            id: 'alksdfjalskj', 
            bracketTitle:'bracket from node', 
            bracketBuyIn: "2",
            bracketPlayer1:'name', 
            bracketPlayer2:'name2',
            bracketPlayer3:'name3',
            bracketPlayer4:'name4',
            bracketPlayer5:'name5',
            bracketPlayer6:'name6', 
            bracketPlayer7:'name7',
            bracketPlayer8:'name8'
        }
    ]; 
    console.log(bracket);
    res.status(200).json({
        message:'Bracket from node',
        bracket:bracket
    });
});
```

'''

In vs code it is defined so I'm confused as to why it doesn't work.

EDIT: the bracket referred to is not a naming error. It's referring to an imported model called Bracket

Comment: It's called `bracket` in the backend and you're trying `brackets` in the frontend. Try adding a `s` in the backend. Also `this.brackets` is assigned value asynchronously, so by the time you do `console.log(this.brackets)` it might still be undefined. The console log should be moved inside the subscription as well.

Comment: I don't think its a naming error. The brackets in the front end is referring to an imported model if I'm correct in what I'm thinking

Comment: I am referring to `brackets` in `bracketData.brackets`. The `brackets` you're trying to retrieve from the response doesn't exist. It's called `bracket`. Because you say `bracket:bracket` in the backend. Either say `brackets:bracket` in the backend or say `bracketData.bracket`  in the front-end.

Comment: You were right. It was a naming error somewhere along the chain. Spent a little while going through everything and eventually found it.. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

There is a naming error, you have

```
 res.status(200).json({
        message:'Bracket from node',
        bracket:bracket
    });
```

calling **bracket**

and in Angular you are using by plural

```
    this.brackets = bracketData.brackets;
```

bracket(s)

leave either bracket, or brackets and it will work fine

Comment: apologies, I should have added in a part then. I'm using a model which is called Bracket so it shouldn't be a naming error

Comment: You were right. It was a naming error somewhere along the chain. Spent a little while going through everything and eventually found it.. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The model you're using in the front-end has **nothing** to do with the value you receive from the back-end. The model is only there to assert the type of the data you're trying to assign to the variable.

But if you see in the backend

```
res.status(200).json({
  message:'Bracket from node',
  bracket:bracket
});
```

You're clearly assigning the object to a property called ***`bracket`***, **NOT** *`brackets`*. To be extra sure, the value you receive from the backend is this

```
{
  message:'Bracket from node',
  bracket: [{
    id: 'alksdfjalskj', 
    bracketTitle:'bracket from node', 
    bracketBuyIn: "2",
    bracketPlayer1:'name', 
    bracketPlayer2:'name2',
    bracketPlayer3:'name3',
    bracketPlayer4:'name4',
    bracketPlayer5:'name5',
    bracketPlayer6:'name6', 
    bracketPlayer7:'name7',
    bracketPlayer8:'name8'
  }]
}
```

So it's called `bracket` **WITHOUT** a `s`.

Now the front-end part.

```js
this.brackets = bracketData.brackets;
```

Here the LHS `this.brackets` for sure abides 100% by the model you've defined. It doesn't jump over any hoops to assign any values that doesn't conform to the model `Bracket` you've defined. But the RHS `bracketData.brackets` doesn't care a single percent about your model. It doesn't have to. It comes from the backend, and that's the only thing it abides to.

If you do a `console.log(bracketData)`, you'll see the following

```
{
  message:'Bracket from node',
  bracket: [{
    id: 'alksdfjalskj', 
    bracketTitle:'bracket from node', 
    bracketBuyIn: "2",
    bracketPlayer1:'name', 
    bracketPlayer2:'name2',
    bracketPlayer3:'name3',
    bracketPlayer4:'name4',
    bracketPlayer5:'name5',
    bracketPlayer6:'name6', 
    bracketPlayer7:'name7',
    bracketPlayer8:'name8'
  }]
}
```

Now, please take a look again closely. You will never be able to find `brackets` property. Because you call it ***`bracket`*** in the backend.

So when you try `bracketData.brackets` there is no data in that property. It might as well be `bracketData.magicData` for all Javascript cares. It **WILL** return `undefined` for undefined properties.